# Making calls to API Servers from a frontend web server

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm a little confused about frontend servers making calls to API Servers.

When I access a frontend site, the browser connects to the frontend server and the html files are downloaded and copied into my browser. So when i make an API call, is the call being made from frontend web server or from the browser?

Comment: What is "frontend web server"?

Comment: "So when i make an API call, is the call being made from frontend web server or from the browser?" — How should we know? It is your code. You could write code that runs on the client and connects to the API server. You could write code that runs on the frontend server and connects to the API server. You could write isomorphic code (e.g. with Next.js) that does both.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a frontend web server. When you connect to a website on the web, your computer connects to a web server, which then sends the requested files back to your browser.

When you make an API call, the same thing is essentially happening. You are either requesting or sending data to a server. The question as to where the call originates from depends on what you are using to call said server. If it's a web browser, then yeah it's the browser who's responsible for sending the request

Comment: "There is no such thing as a frontend web server" — There is. It's a very common industry term. It refers to a server which hosts HTML / JS / CSS for a website (as opposed to one which provides APIs via web services).

Comment: Since he uses the term "browser" in the very next sentence, and the question doesn't make sense if you replace "frontend servers" with "browser" in the first sentence, that doesn't seem likely.

Comment: yes, my understanding of web server is just a server which hosts the html files - the nice UI stuff. when there is a network request from this UI, where does this request originate from? the browser (displaying the UI) or does it connect back to the web server to make the request (Losel's exaplanation)?

sorry if if its a simple question, just tryna understand more of the infra side of stuff. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be referring to the front-end framework like Vue, Angular, etc. If you use Vue for example, you can make API call from there (the front-end) using a specified package like axios.

Comment: It's more likely that, when they said "frontend servers", they meant "frontend servers" and not SPA framework.

Comment: so lets say i'm using axios to make a request, from say... componentdidmount. where does this call originate from? does it originate from the react server or does it originate from the browser?